# unsupported class file major version 63

Tags: java, flutter, gradle, semantic-analysis, java-19

I am trying to run my flutter project in VScode. But this error is * shown. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

- Java version is 19.0.1
- gradle version is 7.1.2
- Flutter 3.3.9

Tools

• Dart 2.18.5

• DevTools 2.15.0

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Nish\face_recognition\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\7.1\scripts\el377zxjtiubuolyxhieyiuv6).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

Comment: Class file version "63" corresponds to Java 19.  PROBLEM: You're compiling classes for Java 19 (like you expect) ... but your Gradle JRE is a *lower* Java version!  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74840295/421195.  If you were using Android Studio (vs. VSCode), this would also be applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74840295/421195, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/75221829/421195